# Router greatly slowing down internet connection speed

Tags: networking, router, internet

I have a router which shares the connection in my house between different computers. I dont need a modem; I can also plug in a pc directly to ethernet cable in my house to gain internet access.

I noticed my connection is almost 10 times faster when I connect my PC directly without the router. How can I achieve similar speed while still sharing the connection between different devices (wired and wlan) ?

Internet speed in both cases (with router and without) was determined both by www.speedtest.net and further verified by personal experience in online games, video sites and so on.

Things I have tried, but the issue of slow speed stays exactly the same:
- I made sure only 1 device was connected to the router
- Tried two routers - router models used: netgear wnr2200, d-link dir-615
- Tried to change ethernet cables
- Tried to change router settings (disabling NAT, UPnP, DHCP server)
- Tried to update router firmware
- Tried to reset routers to factory settings
- Tried restarting routers (obviously)
- Tried to google and look for help, but I guess I lack the knowledge to apply the 
information for my specific case so help would be appreciated!

Comment: I am going to guess your computer has a 10/100/1000 port and your router does not.  Looking both router's specification proves this might be the case.  You don't indicate the network adapater used on your computer.  The sheer fact you noticed a 10 times factor also indicates this might be the cause.

Comment: I had a similar issue and it turned out that the cable was faulty, you might want to test your cable or get a new one:http://superuser.com/questions/337132/how-do-i-find-out-the-speed-of-an-ethernet-cable

Comment: The network adapter on the PC i used to test with and without router is Qualcomm Atheros AR8151 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller (NDIS 6.30).

Comment: Any router with Gigabit ports will return your speed to you.

Comment: @user267621 - Your computer has an ethernet controller that is 10x faster then your router's ethernet controller.

Comment: Thanks! I don't get how that didnt occur to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your computer has an ethernet controller that is 10x faster then your router's ethernet controller.  You want a router that is not only Gigabit WAN, but has Gigabit LAN ports as well (the ports your PC connects to).

The router then will be able to keep up with your connection's transfer rates.